# Use column combinations to find data mismatch in rows pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

What's the best way to get all cell values based on a combination of column values?

Sample dataframe One:

```
  Stock                         Name  Price
0    AMD       Advanced Micro Devices    100
1     GE     General Electric Company    200
2    BAC  Bank of America Corporation    300
3   AAPL                   Apple Inc.    500
4   MSFT        Microsoft Corporation   1000
5  GOOGL                Alphabet Inc.   2000
```

Sample dataframe Two:

```
  Stock                         Name  Price
0    AMD       Advanced Micro Devices    100
1     GE     General Electric Company    200
2    BAC  Branch of America Corporation  300
3   AAPL                   Apple Inc.    500
4   MSFT        Microsoft Corporation   1000
5  GOOGL                Alphabet Inc.   2000
```

For example: I want to use (Stock and Name) as key columns and then compare the datasets. The goal is to print the mismatch entries between the two datasets with the Stock+Name columns used as a combination key.

I'm using Pandas/Python3.7

Sample Output:

> BAC  Bank of America Corporation 300 --- BAC  Branch of America
>   Corporation  300

Comment: Do you have stock names constant between both the DataFrames or `Stock` name also be mismatched?

Comment: Stock names are consistent between the dataframes - but other columns associated with it can be different - which I want to identify.

Comment: @ Greedy coder, then my given answer fits into  your solution to get the match as you want.

Comment: Greedy coder, you can upvote  and mark the accepted answer which fits into your requirement  this is how it will be moved from the un-answered queue.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, a FULL INNER JOIN using `merge` + `query`?

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Stock').query('Name_x != Name_y')

  Stock                       Name_x  Price_x                         Name_y  Price_y
2   BAC  Bank of America Corporation      300  Branch of America Corporation      300
```

---

Or, a slightly different solution with `map`, you can use to get the stock symbols:

```
m = df1.Stock.map(df2.set_index('Stock').Name).ne(df1.Name)
symbols = df1.loc[m, 'Stock']

print(symbols)
2    BAC
Name: Stock, dtype: object
```

And then access each DataFrame row by stock symbol:

```
df1[df1.Stock.isin(symbols)]
  Stock                         Name  Price
2   BAC  Bank of America Corporation    300

df2[df2.Stock.isin(symbols)]
  Stock                           Name  Price
2   BAC  Branch of America Corporation    300
```

Comment: may the Name same but the Stock does not ?

Comment: @W-B Good question, it may be possible but looking at this stock data, I don't know whether it will be an issue... will wait for OP :)

Comment: The Name field can be different/have errors/typos - that's what I want to catch.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in two dataframes, merging them without condition is pretty straightforward with `.concat`. Once they are joined, here's one way to get the mismatch:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Ticker_y": list("qwerty"),
    "Name_y": list("asdfgh"),
    "Ticker_x": list("qw3r7y"),
    "Name_x": list("as6f8h")
})

mismatch = df1[(df1["Ticker_y"] != df1["Ticker_x"]) & (df1["Name_y"] != df1["Name_x"])]
```

The last line just says "the df only where these conditions are met."

Answer (score 0):

We can use `isin` using the sequence of values to test as it ensures each element in the DataFrame is contained in values

**First DataFrame**

```
>>> df1
   Stock                         Name  Price
0    AMD       Advanced Micro Devices    100
1     GE     General Electric Company    200
2    BAC  Bank of America Corporation    300
3   APPL                   Apple Inc.    500
4   MSFT        Microsoft Corporation   1000
5  GOOGL                Alphabet Inc.   2000
```

**Second DataFrame**

```
>>> df2
   Stock                           Name  Price
0    AMD         Advanced Micro Devices    100
1     GE       General Electric Company    200
2    BAC  Branch of America Corporation    300
3   APPL                     Apple Inc.    500
4   MSFT          Microsoft Corporation   1000
5  GOOGL                  Alphabet Inc.   2000
```

Here you can go..

```
>>> df2[~df2.Name.isin(df1.Name.values)]
  Stock                           Name  Price
2   BAC  Branch of America Corporation    300
```

OR

```
>>> df1[~df1.Name.isin(df2.Name.values)]
  Stock                         Name  Price
2   BAC  Bank of America Corporation    300
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. The idea is to find all rows with the same symbol but different name. This is only going to find those names that are not common across both DataFrames (not the same thing)

Comment: This will work if  `Stock` names constant between both the DataFrames, i have asked that to OP to clarify as it looks similar in the POST.